# How to fix setState() call on render() in my code

Tags: reactjs, components, state, render

With the following code I get the error:

Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

I know why. I call setState() in < BoradRow > and the function re-render my code again what makes infinite loop. In this cases, The solution can be use an  event like onclick/onchange but my "event" that prevents infinite loop is the Math.random
So what should I do for stop see this error?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Board from '../../Components/Board/Board';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            rows: 3,
            columns: 3,
            fruit: null,
            snake: []
        };
    }   

    SetFruitSquareID = (prevFruitID) => {
        const { rows, columns } = this.state;
        const maxSquareID = (rows+2) * (columns+2) - 1;
        let newFruitID = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxSquareID) + 1;
        while (prevFruitID === newFruitID) {
            newFruitID = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxSquareID) + 1;
        }
        this.setState({fruit: newFruitID});
        return newFruitID;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (!this.state.fruit) { //first fruit update
            this.SetFruitSquareID(null);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { rows, columns, fruit } = this.state;
      return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Smart Snake !</h1>
            <Board 
                rows={rows}
                columns={columns}
                fruitID={fruit}
                SetFruitSquareID={this.SetFruitSquareID}
            />
        </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Board.js

```
import React from 'react';
import BoardRow from '../BoardRow/BoardRow';

const boardStructure = (rows) => {
    let isBorderRow = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < rows+2; i++) {
        if (i === 0 || i === rows+1) {
            isBorderRow.push(true);
        } else {
            isBorderRow.push(false);
        }
    } 
    return isBorderRow;
}

const Board = ({ rows, columns, fruitID, SetFruitSquareID }) => {
    const board = boardStructure(rows);
    let BoardRowID = 0;
    return (
        <div className='Board'>
            {
                board.map(isBorderRow => (
                    <BoardRow 
                        key={BoardRowID}
                        rowCounter={BoardRowID++}
                        rows={rows}
                        columns={columns}
                        borderRow={isBorderRow}
                        fruitID={fruitID}
                        SetFruitSquareID={SetFruitSquareID}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Board;
```

BoardRow.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Square from '../Square/Square';
import './BoardRow.css';

let squaresID = 0;

const checkSquareStatus = (fruitID, j, columns, borderRow, SetFruitSquareID) => {
    let isFruitSquare = (fruitID === squaresID);
    const isBorderSquare = (j===0 || j===columns+1 || borderRow);
    while (isFruitSquare && isBorderSquare) {
        fruitID = SetFruitSquareID(fruitID);
        isFruitSquare = (fruitID === squaresID);
    }
    if (isFruitSquare) {
        return 'fruit';
    } else if (isBorderSquare) {
        return 'boardBorder';
    }
    return 'emptyCell';
}

const rowStructure = (columns, isLastRow, borderRow, fruitID, SetFruitSquareID) => {
    let boardRow = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < columns+2; j++) {
        boardRow.push({
            id: squaresID,
            status: checkSquareStatus(fruitID, j, columns, borderRow, SetFruitSquareID)
        });
        squaresID++;
        if (isLastRow && (j === (columns+1))) {
            squaresID = 0;
        }
    }
    return boardRow;
}

const BoardRow = ({ rows, columns, rowCounter, borderRow, fruitID, SetFruitSquareID }) => {
    const isLastRow = (rowCounter === rows+1);
    const boardRow = rowStructure(columns, isLastRow, borderRow, fruitID, SetFruitSquareID);
    return (
        <div className='BoardRow'>
            {
                boardRow.map(square => {
                    const { id, status } = square;
                    return (
                        <Square
                            key={id}
                            id={id}
                            rows={rows}
                            columns={columns}
                            status={status}
                        />
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default BoardRow;
```

Comment: As you said, you shouldn't call `SetFruitSquareID` when you are rendering, you have to call that in another moment, `componentDidMount` or any other life cycle method. You have to split your function, one has to be called to set up the variables and another to generate data, this should be two different actions.

Comment: This is impossible. How can I do it if I need use setState based on the prameters in isBorderSquare that in < BoardRow >?

Comment: @liorbar Do you have a codepen for this?  I am not sure, but I suspect, that you are passing the function incorrectly. What gets rendered from Map method, Is it html div or js object ?

Comment: I believe you are able to generate all your data in your App component and after just pass it down.

Comment: @Mobeen What is Map method?

Comment: @liorbar in Board component, board.map () ....

Comment: @aquilesb I build a board. I user loop for the rows and another loop for the coulmns. I can't understand how to put all the loops in the App component.

Comment: @Mobeen js object

Comment: You just have to create your data structure on the App component. Make all the loops to generate your arrays of rows and columns data. Once it is done, you may store it in your state and pass to your Board component. Inside your Board component, interate the rows. Right now you are generating data inside of each component, because that you are in trouble. `Board`, `BoardRow`, `Square` should be presentation Components. They only should show data and emit events up.

Comment: @aquilesb You gave my idea that helps me so much. Thanks!!